# Where can I find free or buy "next-gen" 3D Assets?

Tags: 3d-meshes, normal-mapping

Usually I buy 3D Assets from sites like turbosquid.com or similar.

My problem is that I have lately implemented glow, normal maps, specular (and specular power) maps and reflection maps and I can't find any models that use those techniques.

So where can I find / buy "next gen" assets (at least models/items with a normal map)?

I have checked for similar posts but those I found are about either free only or 2D or 'ordinary' 3D so I hope this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Changed some of your word selection. It sounds much better this way. (if you don't mind)

Comment: If you're not doing the assets then I guess we can assume you're not an artist. In which case you don't need great quality maps just to test your implementation. http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-adobe-photoshop

Comment: @iamcreasy : no problem, I used to speak/write quite good English but 15 years in France have like downgraded me :-/

Comment: @Jonathan Connell: I'm a game programmer (and occasionally gamdesigner) but no I am definitely not an artist and that's why I'm looking for (good) art. To test the implementation I'd say you should do it with the best art you could find (that's just my opinion though) but I'm not only testing it (the implementation), my game is quite advanced (meaning it works and runs more or less OK) so I'm looking for final assets.

Comment: ps. To whom it might concern: Completely okay to downvote but no one will kill you if you leaves a comment about why. You know, "No punishment without educational value" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are very few normalmaps out there (I still haven't found any, not more than the occasional brick map anyway)  so the solution seems to be that you need to do them yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't really get astounding quality with Crazy Bump...hmm. don't know what exactly you are looking for.

okey, here is another solution. Its called [Insane Bump](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?161305-Insane-Bump-Free-alternative-to-crazy-bump). Its functionality is similar to Crazy Bump. Try it out.

There is an interesting [comparison](http://irrlichtirc.g0dsoft.com/omaremad/insane.pdf) between this two bumpies.

Oh did I mention. Its Free!

Comment: Freeness is goodness!

Comment: I definitely check that one out +1! But what I really would like to find is a place that sells already made items with normalmap, specularmap, specpowmap, glowmap etc.

Comment: Interesting tool, but this isn't answering the question...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [CrazyBump](http://www.crazybump.com/)? It generates normal/displacement/occlusion/specular maps from a single diffuse texture, with astounding quality.

Comment: Tried that and I didn't really got that astounding quality (on the other hand I only tried two textures). I'll check it out again.

Answer (score 1):

http://cgtextures.com/ has a good deal of free textures, and some of them come with normal/spec maps (not that many, though).

Comment: I knew about that one (but maybe not every one did, +1), no normal maps in sight though (it's quite rare).